# Animate Checkbox for a second on clicking the Parent Div

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.btn-option {
  width: 330px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #4c4c4c;
  visibility: visible;
  border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* transition */
  transition: filter 0.3s ease 0.3s;
}

.survey-checkbox {
  position: relative;
}

.survey-checkbox::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background: #efefef;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.option-container {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  row-gap: 20px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .btn-option {
    width: 280px;
  }
}
.btn-option:active {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0 steelblue);
  transition: filter 0s;
}
.btn-option:active {
  background: #fcece8;
  border: 1px solid #e76943;
}
.btn-option:active .survey-checkbox::before {
  background-color: #e76943;
}
.btn-option:not(:active) {
  transition: all 1000ms step-end;
}

.survey-checkbox::before:active {
    background-color: #e76943;
}

.btn-option:active {
    animation: all 1s forwards linear;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div
      class="btn btn-option">
      <span>Good</span><input type="checkbox" class="survey-checkbox" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Guys I want to Animate the Checkbox on clicking the parent div right now the problem is as I'm clicking on the parent div it's working fine as expected but the checkbox is working till the active state is there how can I make it transition same like the div.
To make the Div animate on active state I followed an article

Comment: Can you explain more ? do you want the div to keep its animated form while the checkbox is ticked ? or do you want the checkbox itself to get some animation when `:active` ?

Comment: On clicking the Div I want the checkbox to be ticked for a second and then back to its original state

Comment: Maybe with some next generation css/html you could but otherwise, neither of those 2 have no control over something like a checkbox's value, you need javascript for something like that. I think the reason for your confusion is the css `:active` which does not at all mean a ticked checkbox, `:active` stands for holding left click on an element, you can hold left click on your div and see it remain red forever, it has nothing to do with something being "activated"